# ArrayAdapter off spinner can not be resolved

Tags: android, spinner

I n the below I am facing an problem of that the adapter of the spinner mentioned belwo is not recoginzed despite it followed some example.
the values to be displayed is saved in

```
<string-array />  in the rsources.
```

the eror I am getting is:

```
can not resolve construuctor "ArrayAdapter(....,int, int, strng[])
```

I would appreciate it if you can provide solution quickly

**adapter**:

```
        mGearTypesItems = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.millenium_gear_types);

//ERROR:
//CANTO resolve constructor array adapter

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item_for_type,
            R.id.textviewForGearTypeItems,
            mGearTypesItems);
```

**spinner_item_for_type**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/textviewForGearTypeItems"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="38dp"
  android:layout_gravity="right"
  android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_left_padding"
android:textSize="17sp"
android:background="@color/Aqua"
android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
```

**Spinner ui**

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:entries="@array/millenium_gear_types"/>
```

**UPDATE**

```
  //Error:
  //Canot resolve Symbole createFromResource..from a fragment context

    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new              
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity,
            R.array.millenium_gear_types,
            R.layout.spinner_item_for_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the wrong way to declare and initialize an ArrayAdapter object. You can initialize it using the static method `createFromResource()`.

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.millenium_gear_types
        R.layout.spinner_item_for_type);
```

To learn more about ArrayAdapters, read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter).

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: please find the update above i am using the code you posted in a fragment context..as shown in the update section in the question ,       //Canot resolve Symbole createFromResource..from a fragment context

Comment: This approach should work. Check your code again. I strongly suspect you're placing `new` before the ArrayAdapter initialization. Remove it. Make your code the same as my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
mGearTypesItems = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.millenium_gear_types);

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.spinner_item_for_type,
        R.id.textviewForGearTypeItems,
        mGearTypesItems);
```

to this

```
mGearTypesItems = getActivity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.millenium_gear_types);

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.spinner_item_for_type,
        R.id.textviewForGearTypeItems,
        mGearTypesItems);
```